# Confirmation of Proof: If $p$ is a perfect number, then $1 + 8p$ is a squared number.

Tags: proof-explanation, conjectures, perfect-numbers

I have created a hypothesis:

$$\text{If } p \text{ is a perfect number, then } 1 + 8p \text{ is a squared number.}$$

Could anyone prove/disprove the above statement? I have no idea where to begin, and I discovered this by pure accident when trying to solve a quadratic equation.

---

**Edit:**

I believe that all odd numbers $m$ squared can be expressed as the form $8n + 1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$\begin{align} 3^2 &= 9 = 8\times 1 + 1 \\ 5^2 &= 25 = 8\times 3 + 1 \\ 7^2 &= 49 = 8\times 6 + 1 \end{align}$$

Yes, it is obvious that $n$ is also a triangular number $(1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots)$. Let $m = 2k + 1$, then one has the following: $$(2k + 1)^2 = 8n + 1$$ And $(2k + 1)^2 = 4k(k + 1) + 1$, so it follows, then, that:

$$4k(k + 1) \require{cancel}\cancel{+1} = 8n \cancel{+1} \Rightarrow k(k + 1) = k^2 + k = 2n$$

And since the parity of $r \in \mathbb{N}$ remains the same for $r^k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then our proof stands valid.

Comment: $6728=2^3*29^2$ so $29^2$ can be factored out straight away. You are left with $1+2^3*p$

Comment: Ok. So, is $1 + 8p$ a squared number? Oh wait, hey James!

Comment: Yes. All you need do is expand $\left(2^{n+1}-1\right)^2$, then after some basic algebra all is revealed.

Comment: I didn't think. I just saw something, and thought "ooh this is going to be tough" because I have never looked at a problem like this before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true for even perfect numbers, at least. Every even perfect number can be written as $2^{n-1} (2^n - 1)$, for some $n$, which is necessarily 
a triangle number. $29^2 + 6728p = 29^2 (1 + 8p)$, but it is a well known (and easy to prove) fact that if $p$ is triangular, then $1+8p$ is a square.

Comment: which is why we also have solutions like $1, 3, 10$ for p. Ok. Thank you very much :) $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 1):

(We briefly discuss the case for odd $n$ here.)

If $n$ is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), then $1+8n$ is a square.  (Note that *even perfect numbers* are triangular, since they can be written in the form $\frac{M_p(M_p + 1)}{2}$, where $M_p$ is a [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).)

In this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234528), we consider the problem of determining whether an *odd perfect number* is triangular.  Note that it appears as though this is, simple as it may seem, still open.